# search algorithm using sentinel

Tags: java, algorithm

i am trying to do search algorithm using sentinel which reduce  time to 3.87n nanoseconds
 for example compare to this code

```
 int search (int t ){    
 for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
  if (x[i]==t)
   return i;
  return -1;
}
```

it takes  4.06  nanoseconds

so i am trying to optimize it here is code

```
public class Search{

public static int search(int a[], int t) {
int i;
int p=0;
 int n=a.length;
int hold;
 hold=a[n-1];
 a[n-1]=t;
  for ( i=0;;i++)
  if (a[i]==t)  break;
    a[n-1]=t;
  if (i==n){
 p= -1;
} else{
   p= i;
}
return p;
}

public static  void main(String[]args){
int t=-1;
int a[]=new int[]{4,5,2,6,8,7,9};
 System.out.println(search(a,t));  
}
}
```

but is show me that 9 is at position 6 which is correct but if t =1 or something else  which is not array  it show me position 6 too please help

Comment: Can you rephrase your question in a bit more polished English? And reformat your code snippet, I can't believe all this whitespace is necessary.

Comment: Your second algorithm will not work faster.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496013/is-this-linear-search-implementation-actually-useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you look `t=-1` in array `a = [4,5,2,6,8,7,9]`.
You ask, why the result is 6.
Look,

```
public class Search {

public static int search(int a[], int t) {
  int i;
  int p=0;
  int n=a.length;  // n = 7
  int hold;
  hold=a[n-1];  // hold = a[6] = 9; a[6] - is the last element.
  a[n-1]=t;  // a[6] = -1;
  for ( i=0;;i++)
    if (a[i]==t)  break;  // it will break, when i = 6, cause a[6] = -1;
  // after this root finished, i = 6.
  a[n-1]=t;  // a[6] = -1; again ^^
  if (i==n){  // i!=n, 6!=7.
    p= -1;
  } else{  // this branch will work.
    p= i;  // p = 6;
  }
  return p;  // return 6;
}
```

Comment: It means that this code works as it should work (But it doesn't search character correctly). Don't write your own methods, use already existing.

Comment: ok      thanks   but it is not my own it is from programming pearls

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Search {

public static int search(int a[], int t) {
  int i=0;
  try {
    for(i=0;;i++)
      if(t==a[i])
        return i;
}
  catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
    return -1;    
}
}
```

try-catch removes the swaping problem with sentinel

Comment: Shouldn't use exceptions for control flow or as a substitute for checking pre-conditions like `i < a.length`.