# What is the fastest search which can be done on a non-sorted array?

Tags: c, search, data-structures

How to search fast in a non-sorted array? I am unable to think of any other search mechanism apart from linear search.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: The fact that you're asking about speed seems to imply you want to make many such lookups... which means you could create an auxiliary structure, perhaps... a sorted array (perhaps of pointers to the originals instead of copies). Is there some reason you're restricted to an unsorted array?

Comment: Yeah, I cannot sort the array each time an insertion is done as that will be more expensive for me. Linear search is less expensive compared to that.

Comment: @Jay: Of course, it all depends on your exact situation. If your performance bottleneck is in the (linear) search, then there's probably a better alternative - whether it's sorting while constructing (which conceivably could be cheap, with binary search and using an array of pointers/indices rather than moving around the actual objects) or sorting once at the end.

Comment: Maybe you are looking at the problem the wrong way. You say you cannot sort the array every time there is an insertion into it. So wouldn't be better to sort the array and then insert an element in a way that it will remain sorted? Or this is not possible? Please specify what problem you try to solve, that way you might get a better answer.

Comment: @Jay: If can use a red-black tree (for example) instead of an array, insert and search are both O(log n) in the worst case.  If you can use a hash table, they're O(1) in the average case.

Comment: If you need more speed, you will have to trade memory it.  You have a number of options open to you.  Build and maintain a sorted array, maintain a tree (binary, red-black or similar), or build a hash table.  If you have to do many inserts, consider taking a block of inserts and  processing them together.  For example, take 1024 inserts, then quicksort the inserted values, then do an insert sort to merge them with the full, sorted array.  If you don't need to grab ordered chunks of data and just want lookups, use a hash.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, without sorting the data a linear search is about as good as you can do.

Answer (score 4):

Given a truly random non-sorted array, linear search is the best way.

You might be able to do better with some kind of heuristic approach if the data could be assumed to be roughly sorted.

Answer (score 3):

Linearly.  Or sort your array and search that at log time.

Comment: But O(n log n) + O(log n) > O(n). If this is a one time search sorting it is useless. Even faster sorts (if they are applicable) are still only O(n). I agree that if the array is going to be searched multiple times, sorting would be better.

Comment: @Yacoby: unless the data in question is "eligible" for a sort that isn't based on comparisons (a few of which are linear). Even these probably don't pay off for a *single* search, but can still break even with far fewer searches.

Answer (score 2):

There really isn't any kind of optimization to be done without your array being sorted.  All optimizations hinge on having some kind of knowledge about your array being guaranteed.  Without that, you can't assume anything and have to go through each item linearly.

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentionned, a linear search is the way to go.  However, depending upon your setup, the following may or may not be relevant to speeding things up.

If some items are searched for more often than others, a small cache might be useful.  For example, if you are implementing a lookup() operation for a file system (where the data is ultimately stored on disk somewhere), a cache can help immensely.

Can you sort/sift the data at all so that the most commonly looked for items are near the start of the array?

Is it practical to store your data in two sets?  One is sorted, one is unsorted?  The sorted, you should be able to search quickly for your item.  If not found, go to your unsorted list and search linearly through that.  Why?  Although you said it is not practical to insert after every insertion, is it practical/efficient to insert from the unsorted list into the sorted list periodically?

Must it all be in one unsorted array?  Can you put your data into blocks of sorted data?  That is, you might 1000 sorted entries per block.  Searching each sorted block might be faster than searching the entire unsorted list.

Just some ideas.  They might not be applicable to your situation, but hopefully they are helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Once your code is presented with an unsorted list, yes you will need to do a linear search.

There are a couple of things you can do however if it is liable to be searched more than once.

First off, of course, would be sorting the list. It would make the first lookup take quite a while, but subsequent ones would be faster.

Secondly, I'd suggest caching the result. For most usages I've found subsequent lookups have a high likelyhood to be either the same value, or one nearby.

You shouldn't bother with either of these though, unless the list is really large and slow to search. In general, **the less code you can get away with writing, the better off everyone is**.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able, you might consider changing the way the data is stored/created in the first place. Rather than adding items to an array, create a full blown binary tree (or whatever) and work with that.  It makes manipulating the data slightly slower but it shouldn't be as slow as re-sorting the data every time and would make your searches much faster.

Answer (score 1):

There are some clever approaches for optimizing linear search, but in the end none of them really pay of in terms of performance but make the code error-prone and hard to understand. So I'd recommend sticking to a simple linear search (i.e. simple iterating + comparing).

Comment: Method: What are the "clever approaches" that you mentioned?

Comment: Using a sentinel, or counting down instead of up.

Comment: Method: thanks! Read about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_search#Using_a_sentinel).

Comment: @Lazer See my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496013/is-this-linear-search-implementation-actually-useful for further details.