# Check if Number Exists in array which first increases then decreases then increases

Tags: arrays, algorithm, search

Given an array first increasing then decreases at a point and again increases?
find a given number N exists in array or not.

Example 1:

```
Array = 7,8,3,4,5,6 
number = 7
```

answer should be true.

Example 2:

```
Array = 3,4,6,7,8,5,9,10,11  
number = 10
```

answer should be true.
All numbers are unique.

can be done with linear search in `O(N)`,
Can we do that lesser than that. (more efficient)

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2990102/what-is-the-fastest-search-which-can-be-done-on-a-non-sorted-array

Comment: in general, a linear search is as good as you will get for a non-linear array

Comment: What about a modified ternary search, run two or three times? Maybe you could get `O(log N)` time complexity?

Comment: No, for not sorted array search (existence finding) hes O(N) difficulty.

Comment: I don't think we can dismiss this as simply an unsorted array, because of the structure that the array already has.  For example, we'd be able to sort this array in linear time.  But user2357112's example show that this structure doesn't end up helping us with searching.

Comment: There's a little more structure in your examples than you say in your first sentence.  Is the array really two increasing arrays concatenated?  Or are the monotone portions of the array `Omega(N)` in length?

Answer (score 1):

In general, no. Suppose we have the following, in Python:

```
l = range(n)
```

and we randomly stick a `-1` in there:

```
if random.random() < 0.5:
    l[random.randrange(len(l))] = -1
```

The only way to tell if there's a `-1` in the list is to look through every element until you find it or don't. The structure of the list ends up not helping at all.

Answer (score 0):

a linear search is as good as you will get for a non-linear array

Answer (score 0):

**Optimized Algorithm :** -

> 1. Use binary search for key on array if found then return true.
> 2. If not found use linear search

**Time Complexity : -**

**Unsuccessful search :** Here we would do both linear search and binary search hence O(N) for large inputs

**Successful search :**   Here is where our optimization work to some extent. There is on average 1/2 chance that you end up searching in right part of array in binary search . Hence atleast 2 times faster search on average.

Java Code for optimized algorithm with results :-

```
public class UniqueSearch {
    static int linearCount = 0;
    public static boolean binSearch(int[] arr,int key,int high,int low) {


        while(high>=low) {
            int mid = (low+high)/2;
            if(arr[mid]==key) 
                return(true);
            if(arr[mid]<key) {
                low = mid+1;
            }
            else {
                high = mid-1;
            }
        }
        return(false);
    }

    public static boolean linearSearch(int arr[],int key) {
        //System.out.println("linearSearch");
        linearCount++;
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(key==arr[i]) {
                return(true);
            }
        }
        return(false);
    }


    public static boolean optSearch2(int arr[],int key) {

        boolean flag = binSearch(arr, key, arr.length-1,0);
        if(!flag) {
            return(linearSearch(arr, key));
        }
        return(flag);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n = 100000;
        int[] arr = new int[n];
        int error = 0;
        Random r = new Random();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int totalCount = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<1000;i++) {
            error = r.nextInt(arr.length-1);
            for(int k=0;k<error;k++) {
                arr[k] = 2*k+1;
            }
            for(int k=error;k<arr.length;k++) {
                arr[k] = 2*(k-error);
            }
            for(int j=0;j<1000;j++) {
                int x = r.nextInt(arr.length); 
                totalCount++;
                    boolean flag = optSearch2(arr,arr[x]);
                    if(!flag) {
                        System.out.println("error");
                    }

            }
        }
        System.out.println("linearSearch Percentage: "+linearCount*100/totalCount);
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()-start);
    } 
}
```

**Results :**

Run the code and wait for 6-7 secs and you will see that for random successfull search on random array of the special kind as your problem requires linear search about 30% times and rest can be done using binary search in `O(logn)`

Comment: The problem (as user2357112's example shows) is that the decreasing segment may be very small, taking linear time to locate.  So you can't really use that to your advantage.  How would you use a binary search in algorithm 2?

Comment: @Teepeemm in Algorithm 2 you can end up in right array part of array with probability of 1/4 for successful search so for successful searches it gives approx 3/4*n/2 computations which is 3/8*n computations for successful search for large N

Comment: I'll grant that if the decreasing portion of the array is large, then we can make a binary search work.  And if the increasing parts are about the same size, and one of them contains the desired number.  But your worst case must be `O(N)` by the given example, and I don't see how you can beat a linear search with that setup.

Comment: @Teepeemm I am not saying that you cant beat O(N) but you can reduce the probability of linear search to 50% and 50% for binary search for a successfull search

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in O(logN) time complexity

1. Find maximum element in array (call this pivot). Here's the pseudo code

   ```
   public static int getMax(int start, int end){

   if(start==end)
       return start;
   if(start>end)
       return -1;

   int mid = start + (end-start)/2;
   // check if maxima
   if(arr[mid-1]<arr[mid] && arr[mid]>arr[mid+1])
       return mid;

   // check slope
   if(arr[mid-1]<arr[mid] && arr[mid]<arr[mid+1]){
       //increasing slope
       return getMax(mid+1, end);
   }
   if(arr[mid-1]>arr[mid] && arr[mid]>arr[mid+1]){
       return getMax(start, mid-1);
   }

   return -1;
   }
   ```
2. Partition array on pivot element and run two binomial searches for left(increasing) and right(decreasing)

   ```
   findElem(int key, int pivot){
     int index = binSearchInc(start, pivot-1);
     if(index>=0)
       return index;
     else 
       return binSearchDec(pivot+1, end);
   }
   ```

Both steps take O(logN) time for execution.